# which library should i use in UWP to create PDF editor tools?

Tags: pdf, uwp

I am going to create pdf editor tools in uwp using c#. I am not understanding which library i should use ? i only write code to select pdf . but I am not able to edit pdf? and more over I also want to create a pdf editor tool which contain text Highlighter, editor, swigal,strikeout.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please read the entire page, not just the short bullet list at the top.

Comment: Respected  Ken White sir, i don't want to create pdf file .i want to edit it . the documentation you have given is only to create pdf file not to edit it?

Comment: Respectfully, your question asks *which library I should use*, which is a request for a library recommendation. It doesn't matter what you're going to use that library to do; it's still a library recommendation question, and it's still off-topic here. Please read the link I provided, and read the entire page and not just the first paragraph or two.

Comment: you might want to ask in https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the standard library for dealing with PDFs in the UWP platform is:

> Windows.Data.PDF

Of course, this namespace doesn't give you a practical PDF viewer… you will have to arrange it by yourself.

Microsoft has created a UWP sample that demonstrates how to create a PDF viewer and how to deal with theese docs easily.

More infos here:

[Microsoft Docs - Windows.Data.PDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.data.pdf)